# Where does WhatsApp store its 'iCloud Drive backup'

Tags: icloud, data-recovery, whatsapp.app

I'm trying to recover data from my partner's phone and iCloud after her phone backup refused to load back onto her phone (one of many options we're pursuing...)

One of the main sources of data is WhatsApp, [which alleges it has been backing up chat history to iCloud Drive](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/20888066).

I have had no luck of actually finding this file anywhere on iCloud Drive. Either WhatsApp actually keep the file on *their* servers, which would be naughty, or have obscured the file so well that even Apple can't find it. WhatsApp support have been unhelpful so far.

Has anyone had experience with this? I want to get the file into a physical location before I do anything else, for fear of somehow overwriting it...